# I want to put Ubuntu on a bootalbe external USB hard drive

Tags: usb, external-hdd

Putting Ubuntu on a bootable external USB drive looks pretty straight forward but I might need a little help...  I'm only on chapter 8 of a 30+ chapter book...

My problem is I have to 3 different PCs with different motherboards, video cards, etc...  The plan is to carry my USB drive to the PC I want to use, plug it in and reboot the system...

Is this going to be a problem, will Ubuntu configure it's self for the current hardware and let me focus on learning?

Comment: Did you see this Q/A here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator it does not really matter if it's a drive or a stick. Do not install proprietary drivers for different hardwares.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a persistent install or full install to a USB hard drive.
It should work on most computers as long as you don't install proprietary drivers.

It gets a little more complex if one of the computers uses UEFI.